# Postman: Request doesn't match schema when validated against

Tags: yaml, postman, openapi

I'm designing an API following the openAPI 3 and yaml format using Postman and I am running into a bug while trying to validate my API.

I can't validate the API collection even if I get rid of all the endpoints I am working on... And it affects previously created endpoints that I have not modified.

[image: Validation screen]

Even if I confirm the changes, I'll still get a yellow message saying that I have unresolved issues and I'm getting this screen again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution / How I fixed it**

You must go back to the definition and **delete** the litigious endpoints and then **validate** and **sync** the collection. Once it's validated, you should get the green 'No issue found' message in the upper right like below:

[image: Green validation message]

Once you have this, you can go back to **definition** and **add back** the previously deleted litigious endpoints. Once again, check for issues, you should be getting issues because you're adding "new" endpoints, just confirm the changes. You should now be getting the same green message as before in the upper right corner. Issues are fixed.